# Dislocation enchant, does it stack with Splitting enchant?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, rogue

The party Rogue has a new bow: +1, +3 Splitting, +1 Fire, +2 Greater Dislocation 3/day, +8000 Vanishing 1/day and a Quiver with +1 and Keen.

He has the feats Multishot, Opportunist, Savvy Rogue, Combat Reflexes. 
These are all the ones that he uses regularly.

Can the rogue activate his Dislocation (Will save DC 20 or be teleported 30ft.) then Multishot 2 arrows. Do the effects apply to both arrows? If it applies to both arrows, does it carry over to both split arrows? If so, does an enemy need to make four saves or be teleported? Do the teleports stack? Can the rogue seriously move someone up to 120 feet? Plus sneak attack? And then fall damage?

Enchantment descriptions as requested.
Magic Weapon Abilities - Splitting

Any missile fired from a splitting weapon, or an arrow or bolt enchanted with the splitting ability, breaks into two identical missiles before striking the intended target.
V-shaped engravings adorn a splitting weapon or splitting ammunition.
The splitting ability of a ranged weapon (must be a bow, crossbow, arrow, or bolt) only functions if its wielder has the Precise Shot feat.
Any arrow or bolt fired from a splitting weapon magically splits into two missiles in mid-flight. Both missiles are identical, sharing the nonsplitting properties of the original missile; for example, a +1 splitting arrow splits into two +1 arrows in mid-flight. Both missiles strike the same target. Make a separate attack roll for each missile using the same attack bonus.
Aura/Caster Level
Aura: Moderate conjuration (creation)
Caster Level: 7th
Requirements: Craft Magic Arms and Armor, Precise Shot, arrowsplit, +9,000 gp, +720 XP, +18 days; Weight -;
Price: +3 bonus

DISLOCATOR
Price: +1 bonus
Property: Weapon
Caster Level: 12th
Aura: Strong; (DC 21) conjuration
Activation: Swift (mental)
Discolorations in the surface of this weapon
appear, then fade in a random pattern. An
elaborate handle contains a thumb-sized
indent.
When you activate a dislocator weapon,
the next successful attack you make before
the end of your turn causes your target to
be teleported up to 10 feet in any direction
you choose (Will DC 17 negates). You can’t
teleport a target into an occupied space
(such an attempt automatically fails and
wastes the effect).
Projectile weapons bestow this property
on their ammunition.
A dislocator weapon functions three
times per day.
Prerequisites: Craft Magic Arms and
Armor, teleport.

DISLOCATOR, GREAT
[SYNERGY]
Price: +1 bonus
Synergy Prerequisite: Dislocator
Brilliant discolorations in the surface of this
weapon appear, then fade in a random pattern.
An elaborate handle contains a thumb-sized
indent coated in gold fi ligree.
This property functions as a dislocator
weapon (see above), except the target can
be teleported up to 30 feet in any direction
(Will DC 20 negates).

Comment: Could you post the descriptions for Splitting and Greater Dislocation?  I'm not familiar with those modifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key words are **Swift** and **Next Attack**

**Swift Actions**
In D&D3.5e, you may only perform one swift action per turn, even if it is a mental action. So, you would only be able to activate Dislocator once per turn, at the most.

**Next Attack**
Multishot and similar abilities and effects produce additional projectiles as additional attacks. When you're firing two arrows, you're really making two attacks. So the one you designate as the "first" attack will be the "next" attack for Dislocator. Even if you could activate it more than once per turn, you'd have to activate it before each attack, meaning it would have to be in-between the arrows produced by Multishot, which isn't possible.

I really liked this question because of the idea of the idea of hitting someone with so many arrows that they poof and appear in the air, but unfortunately, it's not possible with that set up. Alternatively, you could hire four wizards of sufficiently high enough level to simulate the effect in battle.

> "Look at what my arrows did!"
>
> The four wizards are high-fiving each other in the background while looking mentally exhausted.

**Edit:** One thing I neglected to mention is that Dislocator mentions your next "successful" attack. Meaning that if your first three arrows miss and your fourth arrow hits, they would have to make a Will save. Still, you cannot force your opponent to make more than one Will save per turn in this way.